# Creating workflow to set Image value to a contact's attachment in SharePoint Designer 2007

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss, sharepoint-designer

I'm trying to make a workflow to update a contact's image with the attachment URL.

My workflow is currently set as:

```
If Attachments equals Yes
Set Image to Staff:URL Path    // Current Item:Field
```

I can't seem to get it to point to the attachment image URL.

Is there a better field to call than URL Path?

PS. Any references to be able to program SharePoint 2007 with Visual Studio would be greatly appreciated. I feel too limited in SharePoint Designer in that I can't seem to create my own models/methods or implement my own code.

Thank you.